# Simple ingress from host with microk8s?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, microk8s

I would like to do two things with MicroK8s:

1. Route the host machine (Ubuntu 18.04) ports 80/443 to Microk8s
2. Use something like the simple ingress defined in the [kubernetes.io](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#ingress-controllers) docs

My end goal is to create a single node Kubernetes cluster that sits on the Ubuntu host, then using ingress to route different domains to their respective pods inside the service.

I've been attempting to do this with Microk8s for the past couple of days but can't wrap my head around it.

- The best I've gotten so far is using [MetalLB](https://github.com/google/metallb) to create a load balancer. But this required me to use a free IP address available on my local network rather than the host machines IP address.
- I've also enabled the `default-http-backend` and attempted to export and edit these config files with no success.

As an example this will work on `Minikube` once the ingress add on is enabled, This example shows the base Nginx server image at port 80 on the cluster IP:

```
# ingress-service.yaml

apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
    # - host: nginx.ioo
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: nginx-cluster-ip-service
              servicePort: 80
```

```
# nginx-deployment.yaml

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: nginx
          image: nginx
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
```

```
# nginx-cluster-ip-service

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-cluster-ip-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    component: nginx
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how you enabled `default-http-backend`? When I `describe` my ingress resource I get `<error: endpoints "default-http-backend" not found>`.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

## TLDR

Update the annotation to be `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: public`

## Why

For MicroK8s v1.21, running

```
microk8s enable ingress
```

Will create a `DaemonSet` called `nginx-ingress-microk8s-controller` in the `ingress` namespace.

If you inspect that, there is a flag to set the ingress class:

```
      - args:
        ... omitted ... 
        - --ingress-class=public
        ... omitted ...
```

Therefore in order to work with most examples online, you need to either

1. **Remove** the `--ingress-class=public` argument so it defaults to `nginx`
2. **Update annotations** like `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx` to be `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: public`

Comment: This ensures that an IP is actually set, but in my installation 127.0.0.1 is chosen, which doesn't help much.

Comment: It does help. Specially if all your domains and subdomains points to the same machine where the microk8s is running

Comment: Gosh! Thanks for the answer! I was half thinking of re-implementing my own ingress controller & class. The `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: public` annotation definitely does the trick.

Comment: fyi the annotation has been deprecated, see https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#deprecated-annotation you should try switch it out for `ingressClassName: public`

Answer (score 16):

If I understood you correctly, there are a few ways you might be looking at.

**One would be [MetalLB](https://github.com/google/metallb) which you already mentioned.**

> [MetalLB](https://metallb.universe.tf/) provides a network load-balancer implementation for Kubernetes clusters that do not run on a supported cloud provider, effectively allowing the usage of LoadBalancer Services within any cluster.

You can read the detailed implementation [A pure software solution: MetalLB](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/baremetal/#a-pure-software-solution-metallb)

**Another way would be [Over a NodePort Service](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/baremetal/#over-a-nodeport-service)**

> This approach has a few other limitations one ought to be aware of:
>
> - **Source IP address**
>
> Services of type [NodePort](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport) perform  [source address translation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/services/source-ip/#source-ip-for-services-with-type-nodeport)  by default. This means the source IP of a HTTP request is always  **the IP address of the Kubernetes node that received the request**from the perspective of NGINX.

**You can also use [host network](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/baremetal/#via-the-host-network)**

> In a setup where there is no external load balancer available but using NodePorts is not an option, one can configure `ingress-nginx` Pods to use the network of the host they run on instead of a dedicated network namespace. The benefit of this approach is that the NGINX Ingress controller can bind ports 80 and 443 directly to Kubernetes nodes' network interfaces, without the extra network translation imposed by NodePort Services.

You have to also remember that if you edit the configuration inside the `POD`, it will be gone if the Pod is restarted or it crashes.

I hope this helps you to determine which way to go with your idea.

Comment: speaking of ``ingress-nginx`` you could enable ingress using ``microk8s.enable ingress`` and then use your machine's (node's) ip address in your ingress resource defninition, e.g. ``host: myapp.192-168-0-1.nip.io``, where ``192.168.0.1`` is the ip address of your microk8s node. HTH

Answer (score 6):

The statement "The best I've gotten so far is using MetalLB to create a load balancer." is wrong. You must to use the ingress layer for host traffic routing.

In a bare metal environment you need to configure MetalLB to allow incoming connections from the host to k8s.

First we need a test:

```
curl -H "Host: nginx.ioo" http://HOST_IP
```

What is the result?

1. Network error
2. Error 404 or 503
3. Works!!

If Network error then you need MetalLB

```
microk8s.enable metallb:$(curl ipinfo.io/ip)-$(curl ipinfo.io/ip)
```

Run the test again.

If Network error then you have something wrong. Check host connectivity.

If error 404 (sometimes 503) then you need a ingress rule.

```
# ingress-service.yaml

apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
    - host: nginx.ioo
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: nginx-cluster-ip-service
              servicePort: 80
```

Last test. It should work.

Now you can use ingress to route different domains to their respective pods inside the service.

Comment: Nope, I get 404 before and after making an ingress

Comment: @Arrow_Raider: You can debug your ingress using [NGINX Ingress Controller Troubleshooting](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/troubleshooting/)

Comment: You also have a full example in [Microk8s, MetalLB, ingress-nginx - How to route external traffic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63974879/microk8s-metallb-ingress-nginx-how-to-route-external-traffic/64503673#64503673)

Comment: If you get a 404 try updating the ingress class annotation https://stackoverflow.com/a/67041204/2332785

Answer (score 2):

When using Microk8s 1.21+, this is what an Ingress configuration should look like after running `microk8s enable ingress`:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: frontend-ingress
spec:
  rules:
    - host: staging.resplendentdata.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: frontend-service
                port:
                  number: 80

  ingressClassName: public
```

Answer (score 1):

When using a LoadBalancer (aka **metallb**) there is an important step missing in almost all docs:

**The ingress-controller needs to be exposed to the metallb LoadBalancer.**

```
kubectl expose deploy nginx-deployment --port 80 --type LoadBalancer
```

This can be done by a yaml as well but its way easier to use the cli.

After days of googling i finally came across this tutorial video that opened my eyes.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xYiYIjlAgHY

Answer (score 0):

If you need expose a service publicly with HTTPS and authentication, that may become rather involved, as you need configure a) ingress, b) TLS certificate service - i.e. using Lets Encrypt, c) authentication proxy, d) implement user authorization in your app.

If your K8S cluster is running on a server with no public IP, that brings an additional complication, as you need penetrate NAT.

https://github.com/gwrun/tutorials/tree/main/k8s/pod demonstrates how to securely expose k8s service running on microk8s cluster with no public IP  as publicly accessible HTTPS with OAuth authentication and authorization, using Kubernetes Dashboard as a sample service.

Answer (score 0):

The change of `ingress.class` from `nginx` to `public` proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67041204/9962007) and setting up DNS entry (using my external provider's console) from `*` to my public IP (not a hostname) were the two sufficient conditions to replicate Openshift-style `route` (aka "name-based virtual hosting") under `microk8s` installed on metal.

- More info

Load-balancing between all pod replicas works fine despite no MetalLB being installed (as seen from the output of `gcr.io/google-samples/hello-app`). Even HTTPS worked out-of-the box thanks to self-signed certs auto-generated by the ingress controller.

Answer (score 0):

To install nginx such that it works with the `ingressClass=nginx` use:

```
#https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/
helm upgrade --install ingress-nginx ingress-nginx \
  --repo https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx \
  --namespace ingress-nginx --create-namespace
```