# How to expose Microk8s containers, so they are available from another machine?

Tags: kubernetes, microk8s

I'd like to use [Microk8s](https://microk8s.io/) for playing around Spring Cloud Data Flow, so I installed Multipass on my Windows 10, and in a virtual machine I run an Ubuntu where Microk8s is installed. I'd like to achieve that, all containers run on Ubuntu, which is a headless Virtualbox VM managed by Multipass, but I'd like to be able to connect to the containers from Windows.

The topology looks like this:

**Windows 10**:

- 192.168.1.107 provided by my home router

**Ubuntu** which runs in Virtualbox

- 192.168.52.1 provided by, I believe, Windows for Virtualbox (Virtualbox Host-Only Network)

If I log in Ubuntu `ifconfig` says the following:

```
multipass@scdf:~/scdf/spring-cloud-dataflow$ ifconfig                                                                                                                               
cbr0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500                                                                                                                                  
        inet 10.1.1.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 0.0.0.0                                                                                                                             
        inet6 fe80::c802:9fff:fea2:93f1  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>                                                                                                                   
        ether ca:02:9f:a2:93:f1  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)                                                                                                                                
        RX packets 19890  bytes 6628126 (6.6 MB)                                                                                                                                            
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0                                                                                                                                         
        TX packets 21413  bytes 13988665 (13.9 MB)  

        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0                                                                                                                  
enp0s3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.2.15  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.2.255
        inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:feba:30bb  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:ba:30:bb  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 208972  bytes 273941063 (273.9 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 24249  bytes 2084939 (2.0 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 157483  bytes 40950239 (40.9 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 157483  bytes 40950239 (40.9 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

`microk8s.kubectl get all` says the following, it's been executed in Ubuntu:

```
multipass@scdf:~/scdf/spring-cloud-dataflow$ microk8s.kubectl get all
NAME                                          READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/default-http-backend-5d5ff5d4f5-6ttvd     1/1     Running   1          29m
pod/kafka-broker-64445d8596-88rl6             1/1     Running   24         98m
pod/kafka-zk-77bdb5bcbb-qjxfh                 1/1     Running   4          98m
pod/mysql-bdd598966-nknwk                     0/1     Pending   0          87m
pod/nginx-ingress-microk8s-controller-dh28n   1/1     Running   1          29m


NAME                           TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
service/default-http-backend   ClusterIP      10.152.183.57    <none>        80/TCP                       29m
service/kafka                  ClusterIP      10.152.183.194   <none>        9092/TCP                     98m
service/kafka-zk               ClusterIP      10.152.183.80    <none>        2181/TCP,2888/TCP,3888/TCP   98m
service/kubernetes             ClusterIP      10.152.183.1     <none>        443/TCP                      100m
service/mysql                  ClusterIP      10.152.183.113   <none>        3306/TCP                     87m
service/scdf-server            LoadBalancer   10.152.183.122   <pending>     80:32548/TCP                 80m
service/skipper                LoadBalancer   10.152.183.163   <pending>     80:30955/TCP                 81m

NAME                                               DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR   AGE
daemonset.apps/nginx-ingress-microk8s-controller   1         1         1       1            1           <none>          29m

NAME                                   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/default-http-backend   1/1     1            1           29m
deployment.apps/kafka-broker           1/1     1            1           98m
deployment.apps/kafka-zk               1/1     1            1           98m
deployment.apps/mysql                  0/1     1            0           87m
deployment.apps/scdf-server            0/1     0            0           80m
deployment.apps/skipper                0/1     0            0           82m

NAME                                              DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/default-http-backend-5d5ff5d4f5   1         1         1       29m
replicaset.apps/kafka-broker-64445d8596           1         1         1       98m
replicaset.apps/kafka-zk-77bdb5bcbb               1         1         1       98m
replicaset.apps/mysql-bdd598966                   1         1         0       87m
replicaset.apps/scdf-server-6988d7795f            1         0         0       80m
replicaset.apps/skipper-5957946bf5                1         0         0       82m
```

As you can see there are two `<Pending>` status for external IP addresses. I believe those should be exposed in order to be able to connect to.

I did what I found in [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateless-application/expose-external-ip-address/) help, but I couldn't reach that the server gets external IP.

What I'm doing here wrong?
Is Microk8s able to expose its containers?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You are right, if you want to connect to your cluster from outside, you have to expose service as `LoadBalancer` or `NodePort`.

Unfortunately, as you are not using any cloud provider which support `LoadBalancer` (like AWS or GCP which provides External-IPs) you will be not able to expose service as `LoadBalancer` (service stuck on `Pending` state). As describe [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/#publishing-services-service-types):

> LoadBalancer: Exposes the Service externally using a cloud provider’s
> load balancer. NodePort and ClusterIP Services, to which the external
> load balancer routes, are automatically created.

As default in Microk8s you can use only services like `NodePort` and `ClusterIP`.

With your setup you can use `NodePort`, `ClusterIP` with `Ingress` or MetalLB. If you will use `Ingress` you have to remember to enable `ingress` and `dns` addons in `Microk8s`. It can be done by `$ microk8s.enable dns ingress`.

In short. Options you have are:

1. Use `NodePort`
2. Use [Ingress Controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#ingress-controllers)
3. Set `Endpoints` in your YAMLs or use [MetalLB](https://metallb.universe.tf/configuration/) and point Endpoints.

In Addition you can check similar case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44110876/kubernetes-service-external-ip-pending) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54506269/simple-ingress-from-host-with-microk8s).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try simply adding to your `Service` (of the `spec.type: LoadBalancer` type) the so-called **External IPs** (see [k8s docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#external-ips) and [OCP docs](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.12/networking/configuring_ingress_cluster_traffic/configuring-externalip.html), the latter incl. security considerations):

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
[..]
spec:
[..]
  externalIPs:
  - <external-ip>
  ports:
  - port: 8001 # port exposed to the k8s cluster
    targetPort: 8000 # containerized app's server port
  [..]
  type: LoadBalancer
```

Or using `kubectl` with the `--external-ip` flag:

```
kubectl expose [..] --type='LoadBalancer' --port=8001 --target-port=8000 [..] --external-ip='<external-ip>'
```

You also need to:

- enable the [NGINX Ingress Controller](https://microk8s.io/docs/addon-ingress) add-on in MicroK8s:

```
$ microk8s enable ingress
```

- set up an Ingress, with its `backend` pointing to your service name and port (the one exposed to the cluster, not the outside world):

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: <app-name>
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: <app-name>
            port:
              number: 8001
```

Then finally you can test the app with `curl <external-ip>:80` or browse to `http://<external-ip-or-hostname>`.

---

Other options of routing traffic from the internet to the k8s cluster are rather limiting, requiring either using cloud providers network load balancers ("proper" `spec.type: LoadBalancer`) or an inconveniently large port number (`spec.type: NodePort`), likely to be blocked by your users corporate networks setups).