# getting 404 not found from nginx , Fake certificate is loading after installing SSL

Tags: nginx, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks, nginx-ingress, ingress-controller

we are using aks k8s for our application
we have installed ssl certs as secrets  .we have ngnix-ingress in separate name space .
once I applied certificates , I am getting 404 Not Found from nginx,
from nginx side I verified everything , controller reloaded with new configarations  .
but I am not getting home page  , any Idea on this issue
Ref : [nginx Ingress installtion link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-own-tls?tabs=azure-cli)
with curl I am able to get proper certificate installed

```
curl -v -k --resolve azx-devops-monitoring.aaa.com:443:10.11.6.100 https://azx-devops-monitoring.aaa.com
```

but with browser once I tried I am getting 404 not found and the certificate also nginx fake certificate .
url i tried

```
https://azx-devops-monitoring.aaa.com
https://10.11.6.100
```

```
kubectl describe ingress st2-ingress -n st2
Name:             st2-ingress
Namespace:        st2
Address:          10.ab.6.xyz
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<error: endpoints "default-http-backend" not found>)
Rules:
  Host        Path  Backends
  ----        ----  --------
  *
              /   stackstormha-st2web:80 (10.xxx.1.18x:80,10.xxx.3.18y:80)
Annotations:  kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
Events:       <none>

kubectl describe secret aks-ingress-tls -n st2
Name:         aks-ingress-tls
Namespace:    st2
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>

Type:  kubernetes.io/tls
```

Comment: Can you provide the output of the command `kubectl describe ingress <“ingress name”> `? Also output of command `kubectl get certificate`.  It is described in [detail here](https://cert-manager.io/docs/faq/troubleshooting/).

Comment: there is no output for kubectl get certificate

Comment: You have `error: endpoints "default-http-backend" not found`  good solution for fix it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63558461/endpoints-default-http-backend-not-found-in-ingress-resource). What does the console output to you? How did you set up the cluster (your config file)? It is important to reproduce your problem.