# Microk8s dashboard using nginx-ingress via http not working (Error: `no matches for kind "Ingress" in version "extensions/v1beta1"`)

Tags: http, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, microk8s

I have microk8s v1.22.2 running on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS.

Output from `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 main
```

Excerpt from `microk8s status`:

```
addons:
  enabled:
    dashboard            # The Kubernetes dashboard
    ha-cluster           # Configure high availability on the current node
    ingress              # Ingress controller for external access
    metrics-server       # K8s Metrics Server for API access to service metrics
```

I checked for the running dashboard (`kubectl get all --all-namespaces`):

```
NAMESPACE     NAME                                             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   pod/calico-node-2jltr                            1/1     Running   0          23m
kube-system   pod/calico-kube-controllers-f744bf684-d77hv      1/1     Running   0          23m
kube-system   pod/metrics-server-85df567dd8-jd6gj              1/1     Running   0          22m
kube-system   pod/kubernetes-dashboard-59699458b-pb5jb         1/1     Running   0          21m
kube-system   pod/dashboard-metrics-scraper-58d4977855-94nsp   1/1     Running   0          21m
ingress       pod/nginx-ingress-microk8s-controller-qf5pm      1/1     Running   0          21m

NAMESPACE     NAME                                TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
default       service/kubernetes                  ClusterIP   10.152.183.1     <none>        443/TCP    23m
kube-system   service/metrics-server              ClusterIP   10.152.183.81    <none>        443/TCP    22m
kube-system   service/kubernetes-dashboard        ClusterIP   10.152.183.103   <none>        443/TCP    22m
kube-system   service/dashboard-metrics-scraper   ClusterIP   10.152.183.197   <none>        8000/TCP   22m

NAMESPACE     NAME                                               DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR            AGE
kube-system   daemonset.apps/calico-node                         1         1         1       1            1           kubernetes.io/os=linux   23m
ingress       daemonset.apps/nginx-ingress-microk8s-controller   1         1         1       1            1           <none>                   22m

NAMESPACE     NAME                                        READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
kube-system   deployment.apps/calico-kube-controllers     1/1     1            1           23m
kube-system   deployment.apps/metrics-server              1/1     1            1           22m
kube-system   deployment.apps/kubernetes-dashboard        1/1     1            1           22m
kube-system   deployment.apps/dashboard-metrics-scraper   1/1     1            1           22m

NAMESPACE     NAME                                                   DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
kube-system   replicaset.apps/calico-kube-controllers-69d7f794d9     0         0         0       23m
kube-system   replicaset.apps/calico-kube-controllers-f744bf684      1         1         1       23m
kube-system   replicaset.apps/metrics-server-85df567dd8              1         1         1       22m
kube-system   replicaset.apps/kubernetes-dashboard-59699458b         1         1         1       21m
kube-system   replicaset.apps/dashboard-metrics-scraper-58d4977855   1         1         1       21m
```

I want to expose the microk8s dashboard within my local network to access it through `http://main/dashboard/`

To do so, I did the following `nano ingress.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: public
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
  name: dashboard
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  rules:
  - host: main
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: kubernetes-dashboard
          servicePort: 443
        path: /
```

Enabling the ingress-config through `kubectl apply -f ingress.yaml` gave the following error:

```
error: unable to recognize "ingress.yaml": no matches for kind "Ingress" in version "extensions/v1beta1"
```

Help would be much appreciated, thanks!

**Update:**
@harsh-manvar pointed out a mismatch in the config version. I have rewritten ingress.yaml to a very stripped down version:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: dashboard
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /dashboard
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: kubernetes-dashboard
            port:
              number: 443
```

Applying this works. Also, the ingress rule gets created.

```
NAMESPACE     NAME        CLASS    HOSTS   ADDRESS     PORTS   AGE
kube-system   dashboard   public   *       127.0.0.1   80      11m
```

However, when I access the dashboard through `http://<ip-of-kubernetes-master>/dashboard`, I get a `400` error.

Log from the ingress controller:

```
192.168.0.123 - - [10/Oct/2021:21:38:47 +0000] "GET /dashboard HTTP/1.1" 400 54 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.71 Safari/537.36" 466 0.002 [kube-system-kubernetes-dashboard-443] [] 10.1.76.3:8443 48 0.000 400 ca0946230759edfbaaf9d94f3d5c959a
```

Does the dashboard also need to be exposed using the `microk8s proxy`? I thought the ingress controller would take care of this, or did I misunderstand this?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

To fix the error `error: unable to recognize "ingress.yaml": no matches for kind "Ingress" in version "extensions/v1beta1` you need to set `apiVersion` to the  `networking.k8s.io/v1`. From the [Kubernetes v1.16 article about deprecated APIs](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/07/18/api-deprecations-in-1-16/):

> - NetworkPolicy in the  **extensions/v1beta1**  API version is no longer served
>   -   Migrate to use the  **networking.k8s.io/v1**  API version, available since v1.8. Existing persisted data can be retrieved/updated via the new version.

Now moving to the second issue. You need to add a few annotations and make few changes in your Ingress definition to make dashboard properly exposed on the microk8s cluster:

- add [`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2` annotation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/)
- add [`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: | rewrite ^(/dashboard)$ $1/ redirect;` annotation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#configuration-snippet)
- change `path: /dashboard` to `path: /dashboard(/|$)(.*)`

We need them to properly forward the request to the backend pods - [good explanation in this article](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/eks-kubernetes-dashboard-custom-path/):

> **Note:** The "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target" annotation rewrites the URL before forwarding the request to the backend pods. In **/dashboard(/|$)(.*)** for **path**, **(.*)** stores the dynamic URL that's generated while accessing the Kubernetes Dashboard. The "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target" annotation replaces the captured data in the URL before forwarding the request to the **kubernetes-dashboard** service. The "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet" annotation rewrites the URL to add a trailing slash ("/") only if **ALB-URL/dashboard** is accessed.

Also we need another two changes:

- add [`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"` annotation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#backend-protocol) to tell NGINX Ingress to communicate with Dashboard service using HTTPs
- add `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: public` annotation [to use NGINX Ingress created by microk8s `ingress` plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67041204/16391991)

After implementing everything above, the final YAML file looks like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      rewrite ^(/dashboard)$ $1/ redirect;
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: public
  name: dashboard
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /dashboard(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: kubernetes-dashboard
            port:
              number: 443
```

It should work fine. No need to run `microk8s proxy` command.

Answer (score 8):

```
error: unable to recognize "ingress.yaml": no matches for kind "Ingress" in version "extensions/v1beta1"
```

it's due to the mismatch in the ingress API version.

You are running the **v1.22.2** while API version in YAML is old.

Good example : https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/

you are using the older ingress API version in your YAML which is `extensions/v1beta1`.

You need to change this based on ingress version and K8s version you are running.

This is for version **1.19** in K8s and will work in 1.22 also

Example :

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: minimal-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /testpath
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: test
            port:
              number: 80
```

Reference : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/

Answer (score 4):

**If you get this error trying to install an AWS ALB controller <2.0!** here's what happens:
The ALB controller v1.x.x uses the `networking.k8s.io/v1beta1` API, which turns to be deleted upon new versions of k8s (https://kubernetes.io/blog/2021/07/14/upcoming-changes-in-kubernetes-1-22/#api-changes)

> All beta Ingress APIs (the extensions/v1beta1 and networking.k8s.io/v1beta1 API versions)

- The recommended solution is to upgrade your ALB version.