# Microk8s ingress with nginx - why this setup doesn't work?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I'd like to put together a dev environment where there is a kubernetes cluster (I intend to use Microk8s with multiple nodes at the end). The reason is that I'll have a prod system running on this cluster with test environments, and eventually when a new PR is created based on the PR id a totally new system will be created and the url will be different. Something like this: prod system: http://my-system.com, test: http://test-pr-63.my-system.com.

But, first I need a kubernetes with a minimal ingress listening on an IP address and able to route traffic to services/pods, based on URL. I'm not a well versed in kubernetes space.

The end result is always `connection refused` when I call the IP via curl, and I don't know why.

I do the following steps to install the system on a newly created microk8s environment on m Macbook Pro.

## Status

```
microk8s is running
high-availability: no
  datastore master nodes: 127.0.0.1:19001
  datastore standby nodes: none
addons:
  enabled:
    ha-cluster           # Configure high availability on the current node
  disabled:
```

## Enable services

```
~/: microk8s enable ingress dns storage
Enabling Ingress
ingressclass.networking.k8s.io/public created
namespace/ingress created
serviceaccount/nginx-ingress-microk8s-serviceaccount created
clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/nginx-ingress-microk8s-clusterrole created
role.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/nginx-ingress-microk8s-role created
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/nginx-ingress-microk8s created
rolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/nginx-ingress-microk8s created
configmap/nginx-load-balancer-microk8s-conf created
configmap/nginx-ingress-tcp-microk8s-conf created
configmap/nginx-ingress-udp-microk8s-conf created
daemonset.apps/nginx-ingress-microk8s-controller created
Ingress is enabled
Enabling DNS
Applying manifest
serviceaccount/coredns created
configmap/coredns created
Warning: spec.template.metadata.annotations[scheduler.alpha.kubernetes.io/critical-pod]: non-functional in v1.16+; use the "priorityClassName" field instead
deployment.apps/coredns created
service/kube-dns created
clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/coredns created
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/coredns created
Restarting kubelet
DNS is enabled
Enabling default storage class
deployment.apps/hostpath-provisioner created
storageclass.storage.k8s.io/microk8s-hostpath created
serviceaccount/microk8s-hostpath created
clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/microk8s-hostpath created
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/microk8s-hostpath created
Storage will be available soon
```

The cluster looks like this:

```
 ~/: kubectl get all --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME                                           READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
ingress       pod/nginx-ingress-microk8s-controller-5w7tw    1/1     Running   0          92s
kube-system   pod/coredns-7f9c69c78c-94nbl                   1/1     Running   0          91s
kube-system   pod/calico-kube-controllers-69d7f794d9-wz79l   1/1     Running   0          4m10s
kube-system   pod/calico-node-2r6bv                          1/1     Running   0          4m11s
kube-system   pod/hostpath-provisioner-566686b959-8rwkv      1/1     Running   0          14s

NAMESPACE     NAME                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                  AGE
default       service/kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.152.183.1    <none>        443/TCP                  7m59s
kube-system   service/kube-dns     ClusterIP   10.152.183.10   <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP   91s

NAMESPACE     NAME                                               DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR            AGE
kube-system   daemonset.apps/calico-node                         1         1         1       1            1           kubernetes.io/os=linux   4m48s
ingress       daemonset.apps/nginx-ingress-microk8s-controller   1         1         1       1            1           <none>                   92s

NAMESPACE     NAME                                      READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
kube-system   deployment.apps/calico-kube-controllers   1/1     1            1           4m48s
kube-system   deployment.apps/coredns                   1/1     1            1           92s
kube-system   deployment.apps/hostpath-provisioner      1/1     1            1           79s

NAMESPACE     NAME                                                 DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
kube-system   replicaset.apps/calico-kube-controllers-69d7f794d9   1         1         1       4m11s
kube-system   replicaset.apps/coredns-7f9c69c78c                   1         1         1       92s
kube-system   replicaset.apps/hostpath-provisioner-566686b959      1         1         1       14s
```

## Install kafka by helm using bitnamy's chart

```
NAMESPACE     NAME                                           READY   STATUS    RESTARTS      AGE
ingress       pod/nginx-ingress-microk8s-controller-5w7tw    1/1     Running   0             3m55s
kube-system   pod/coredns-7f9c69c78c-94nbl                   1/1     Running   0             3m54s
kube-system   pod/calico-kube-controllers-69d7f794d9-wz79l   1/1     Running   0             6m33s
kube-system   pod/calico-node-2r6bv                          1/1     Running   0             6m34s
kube-system   pod/hostpath-provisioner-566686b959-8rwkv      1/1     Running   0             2m37s
eg            pod/eg-kafka-zookeeper-0                       1/1     Running   0             48s
eg            pod/eg-kafka-zookeeper-1                       1/1     Running   0             48s
eg            pod/eg-kafka-zookeeper-2                       1/1     Running   0             48s
eg            pod/eg-kafka-0                                 1/1     Running   1 (32s ago)   48s
eg            pod/eg-kafka-1                                 1/1     Running   1 (31s ago)   48s
eg            pod/eg-kafka-2                                 1/1     Running   1 (30s ago)   48s

NAMESPACE     NAME                                  TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
default       service/kubernetes                    ClusterIP   10.152.183.1     <none>        443/TCP                      10m
kube-system   service/kube-dns                      ClusterIP   10.152.183.10    <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP       3m54s
eg            service/eg-kafka-zookeeper-headless   ClusterIP   None             <none>        2181/TCP,2888/TCP,3888/TCP   48s
eg            service/eg-kafka                      ClusterIP   10.152.183.18    <none>        9092/TCP                     48s
eg            service/eg-kafka-zookeeper            ClusterIP   10.152.183.140   <none>        2181/TCP,2888/TCP,3888/TCP   48s
eg            service/eg-kafka-headless             ClusterIP   None             <none>        9092/TCP,9093/TCP            48s

NAMESPACE     NAME                                               DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR            AGE
kube-system   daemonset.apps/calico-node                         1         1         1       1            1           kubernetes.io/os=linux   7m11s
ingress       daemonset.apps/nginx-ingress-microk8s-controller   1         1         1       1            1           <none>                   3m55s

NAMESPACE     NAME                                      READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
kube-system   deployment.apps/calico-kube-controllers   1/1     1            1           7m11s
kube-system   deployment.apps/coredns                   1/1     1            1           3m55s
kube-system   deployment.apps/hostpath-provisioner      1/1     1            1           3m42s

NAMESPACE     NAME                                                 DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
kube-system   replicaset.apps/calico-kube-controllers-69d7f794d9   1         1         1       6m34s
kube-system   replicaset.apps/coredns-7f9c69c78c                   1         1         1       3m55s
kube-system   replicaset.apps/hostpath-provisioner-566686b959      1         1         1       2m37s

NAMESPACE   NAME                                  READY   AGE
eg          statefulset.apps/eg-kafka-zookeeper   3/3     48s
eg          statefulset.apps/eg-kafka             3/3     48s
```

## Deploy the single service where to the traffic will be routed

It is a simple webapi using Spring, the image works and spins up without any problem.

```yaml
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      name: webapi
    spec:
      selector:
        app: webapi
      ports:
      - port: 80
        targetPort: 80
    
    ---
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      name: webapi
    spec:
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          app: webapi
      
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: webapi
        
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: webapi
      
            image: ghcr.io/encyclopediagalactica/sourceformats.api.rest/sourceformat-api-rest:latest
            resources:
              limits:
                memory: "1Gi"
                cpu: "500m"
            ports:
            - containerPort: 80
```

`kubectl get all --all-namespaces` the newly added stuff is marked `====>`

```
NAMESPACE     NAME                                           READY   STATUS    RESTARTS        AGE
ingress       pod/nginx-ingress-microk8s-controller-5w7tw    1/1     Running   0               8m45s
kube-system   pod/coredns-7f9c69c78c-94nbl                   1/1     Running   0               8m44s
kube-system   pod/calico-kube-controllers-69d7f794d9-wz79l   1/1     Running   0               11m
kube-system   pod/calico-node-2r6bv                          1/1     Running   0               11m
kube-system   pod/hostpath-provisioner-566686b959-8rwkv      1/1     Running   0               7m27s
eg            pod/eg-kafka-zookeeper-0                       1/1     Running   0               5m38s
eg            pod/eg-kafka-zookeeper-1                       1/1     Running   0               5m38s
eg            pod/eg-kafka-zookeeper-2                       1/1     Running   0               5m38s
eg            pod/eg-kafka-0                                 1/1     Running   1 (5m22s ago)   5m38s
eg            pod/eg-kafka-1                                 1/1     Running   1 (5m21s ago)   5m38s
eg            pod/eg-kafka-2                                 1/1     Running   1 (5m20s ago)   5m38s
====> eg            pod/webapi-7755b88f98-kwsmx                    1/1     Running   0               52s

NAMESPACE     NAME                                  TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
default       service/kubernetes                    ClusterIP   10.152.183.1     <none>        443/TCP                      15m
kube-system   service/kube-dns                      ClusterIP   10.152.183.10    <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP       8m44s
eg            service/eg-kafka-zookeeper-headless   ClusterIP   None             <none>        2181/TCP,2888/TCP,3888/TCP   5m38s
eg            service/eg-kafka                      ClusterIP   10.152.183.18    <none>        9092/TCP                     5m38s
eg            service/eg-kafka-zookeeper            ClusterIP   10.152.183.140   <none>        2181/TCP,2888/TCP,3888/TCP   5m38s
eg            service/eg-kafka-headless             ClusterIP   None             <none>        9092/TCP,9093/TCP            5m38s
====> eg            service/webapi                        ClusterIP   10.152.183.96    <none>        80/TCP                       52s

NAMESPACE     NAME                                               DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR            AGE
kube-system   daemonset.apps/calico-node                         1         1         1       1            1           kubernetes.io/os=linux   12m
ingress       daemonset.apps/nginx-ingress-microk8s-controller   1         1         1       1            1           <none>                   8m45s

NAMESPACE     NAME                                      READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
kube-system   deployment.apps/calico-kube-controllers   1/1     1            1           12m
kube-system   deployment.apps/coredns                   1/1     1            1           8m45s
kube-system   deployment.apps/hostpath-provisioner      1/1     1            1           8m32s
====> eg            deployment.apps/webapi                    1/1     1            1           52s

NAMESPACE     NAME                                                 DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
kube-system   replicaset.apps/calico-kube-controllers-69d7f794d9   1         1         1       11m
kube-system   replicaset.apps/coredns-7f9c69c78c                   1         1         1       8m45s
kube-system   replicaset.apps/hostpath-provisioner-566686b959      1         1         1       7m27s
eg            replicaset.apps/webapi-7755b88f98                    1         1         1       52s

NAMESPACE   NAME                                  READY   AGE
eg          statefulset.apps/eg-kafka-zookeeper   3/3     5m38s
eg          statefulset.apps/eg-kafka             3/3     5m38s
```

## Ingress rule

```yaml
    apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
    kind: Ingress
    metadata:
      name: webapi-ingress
      #annotations:
        #kubernetes.io/ingress.class: public
    spec:
      rules:
      - host: blabla.com
        http:
          paths:
          - pathType: Prefix
            path: "/"
            backend:
              service:
                name: webapi
                port: 
                  number: 80
      ingressClassName: public
```

result:

```
 ~/: kubectl get ingress -n eg
NAME             CLASS    HOSTS        ADDRESS     PORTS   AGE
webapi-ingress   public   blabla.com   127.0.0.1   80      48s
```

**Additional info**:

Regarding the commented out lines. There this this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54506269/simple-ingress-from-host-with-microk8s/67041204#67041204) which points out that the annotations should match. If I follow what is described in the answer the result is the same.
There is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69588941/825968) post which emphasizes using the `ingressClassName` property. If I follow this the end result is the same. The two suggestion cannot be combined because kubernetes throws an error.

## Call the endpoint

```
~/: curl http://blabla.com/get
curl: (7) Failed to connect to blabla.com port 80: Connection refused
```

My `/etc/hosts` looks like the following:

```
    ~/: cat /etc/hosts
    ##
    # Host Database
    #
    # localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
    # when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
    ##
    127.0.0.1       localhost
    255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
    ::1             localhost
    127.0.0.1       blabla.com
    # Added by Docker Desktop
    # To allow the same kube context to work on the host and the container:
    127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal
    # End of section
```

Why `127.0.0.1`? I watched [this video](https://youtu.be/80Ew_fsV4rM?t=860) where Nana says that to whatever IP the ingress rule bound to in the `/etc/hosts` file I have to map it with the domain in order to route the traffic there. It makes sense to me.

I also followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64522733/825968) answer's suggestions and the result is the same.

How about debugging you might ask... So, nginx logs don't say a word. Seems like the traffic doesn't get to nginx.

I can't decide whether I need metallb... but, discouraging that Microk8s docs mentions that some part of the metallb won't work due to Macbook network traffic manipulation.

So, I have tried at least 4-5 scenarios and the result is the same. I assume 1, I either miss something fundamental, or 2, my Macbook has some magic which doesn't let the traffic go the kubernetes..., or, 3, the both, which wouldn't not be a big surprise. :)

Have you tried minikube, you might ask... Yes, I tried. It can't deal with setting up the Kafka instances. Not an option for me.

So, what I'm doing wrong here? Is there a tutorial which helps me to setup this cluster?

Comment: did you find any solution for this

Comment: I don't know really what caused this issue for me. I reinstalled a few times MicroK8s, and put the problem aside for a week. Eventually I could manage the cluster I wanted, but still don't understand what was the issue.